# SQL: Duplicate instances, into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, aggregate-functions

I run a basic SQL query on our database which brings back student data. A student could have multiple instances on different courses, for example:

```
StudentID        StudentFullName        Course        StartDate
123456           J.Bloggs               BA            01/11/2012
123456           J.Bloggs               MBA           01/07/2015
234567           R.Head                 BA            09/04/2014
```

What I'm trying to do is merge the duplicate student record (probably based either on ID or Name) and bring the course data into the same row, leaving the end result ideally looking like this:

```
StudentID        StudentFullName        Course1       StartDate1       Course2    StartDate2
123456           J.Bloggs               BA            01/11/2012       MBA        01/07/2015
234567           R.Head                 BA            09/04/2014
```

There could be instances where students have more than 2 courses, so the code would need to be flexible to allow this (Course3, Course 4 etc).

I would also be looking at running the query looking for students who started what would be 'Course1' after a certain time period (>='2014/08/01').

So far I have only been able to recreate the desired result manually by running the original code and then editing in a spreadsheet (time consuming).

Comment: Read http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/first-normal-form.htm and normalise your database.

Comment: I've read about pivot before, but no idea where to begin. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Especially since your number of courses is flexible, you will not be able to put that into one table. That is, SQL Server does not support "flexible column tables" as a concept.

Instead, your problem might be one of [normalization to the 2NF form](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php).

Consider creating a new table StudentCourses with columns Student ID, Course, Start Date.
A student such as J.Bloggs will have two entries there, while R.Head will only have one entry.
Your current Student table remains with only student information such as name, date of birth, credits, etc.

Then, depending on your needs, you can always build queries or views that pick up that information.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the SQL within any other programming language ? If so you could use an if-Statement to add new columns, but dynamically adding or deleting columns would cause anomalies.
I think that creating a seperate table would get you the best results. You should have three tables then:

**Student** Data(StudentID, StudentFullName)

**Courses**(CourseID, CourseName)

**StudentCourses**(CourseID,StudentID, StartDate)

This is an optimized scheme.

Hope i could help, if not please feel free to ask further questions.

EDIT: This will need more effort maybe, because the courses are stored seperately, but it should be the quickest and most storage-saving solution.
as mentioned in a comment: this is the normalization of the scheme.

Maybe easier would be the scheme with two tables:
StudentData(StudentID, StudentFullName)
StudentCourses(CourseName,StudentID, StartDate)

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to pivot multiple columns is to use aggregate case expressions.

You have to use ROW_NUMBER to determine if the course is course1, course2, etc.. and then simply use the generated ROW_NUMBER in your Case Expression.

```
SELECT  [StudentID],
        [StudentFullName],
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN [Course] END) AS Course1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN [StartDate] END) AS StartDate1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 2 THEN [Course] END) AS Course2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 2 THEN [StartDate] END) AS StartDate2
FROM    (
            SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [StudentID] ORDER BY [StartDate] DESC) Rn
            FROM    Table1
        ) t
GROUP BY [StudentID],
        [StudentFullName]
```

These queries can also be done dynamically by just building the MAX(CASE) portion.